# React : Link to PDF which is in my project folder

Tags: html, reactjs, web

In my React application, I want to link to a PDF from a page.

The PDF is located in `src\assets\`, and I have my component in `src\components\xyz\`.

In my component, I simply do `<a href="<link to pdf>" >Download here</a>`, but clicking on this takes me to `localhost:3000/foo.pdf` which doesn't give me anything.

When I add a `download` attribute to `a` it downloads the file, but I want it to first open in a new tab and then the user can download it from there.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the path to document in url href like this and try.

```
<a href="../assets/{fileName.pdf}" target="_blank"> Download </a>
```